# Atualizar a página depois de 3 cliques no botão

Tags: javascript, button

Desenvolvi um código em JavaScript que gera uma sequência de números aleatórios e queria saber se consigo colocar um limite de 3 cliques nesse botão e após o 3º clique a página é atualizada. Já tentei utilizar a função history.go só que ela atualiza logo quando clica, não depois de 3 cliques

Esse é o código do botão:

```
<center><button onclick="history.go(0)">Clique e gere o código</button></center>
```

tem algum jeito de fazer o history.go ser chamado só depois de 3 cliques?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Voçê não poderia criar um script para isso?

Desta forma:

```js
let clicks = 0;

function clickFunction() {
  clicks += 1;

  if (clicks >= 3) {
    console.log('Clicou mais de 3 vezes!');

    // agora voce executa o history.go(0)
    // window.history.go(0)
  }
}
```

```html
<center>
  <button onclick="clickFunction()">Clique e gere o código</button>
</center>
```

Chegou a tentar dessa forma?
Não sei se entendi direito sua pergunta, mas faça o teste.